# javascript - result of Object.prototype.toString.call with string

Tags: javascript

There is a technical issue I wanted to figure out with `Object.prototype.toString.call`. In javascript, when you call the function **`"call"`**, the first parameter is a reference to **`"this"`**, or the object you are working on. So I was expecting that `Object.prototype.toString.call("aaa")` would yield "aaa", same as when you call `"aaa".toString()`.

Instead, it yields

> "[object String]".

Why is that?

Comment: Because `Object.prototype.toString` is not the same as `String.prototype.toString`

Comment: Basically you are doing the toString of the prototype of the passed object, not a toString of the object itself. It's a method of figuring out what type of object the variable is, instead of simply getting the string representation of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `Object.prototype.toString` is explicitly explained in [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0).

The notable steps are

> 3) Let O be ToObject(this value).
>   7) Else, if O is an exotic String object, let builtinTag be "String".
>   19) Return the String that is the result of concatenating "[object ", tag, and "]".

So as you can see the string literal (which is a primitive type and is not an object) is first converted to the string object, then tagged as a `String` and then the output `[object String]` is returned.

References:

- [19.1.3.6 - `Object.prototype.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring)